# How to query all rows of one column in DynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I just work with AWS DynamoDB in a short of time. I am wondering how can I get the same result with this statement (without WHERE clause):

`SELECT column1 FROM DynamoTable;`

I tried (but failed) with:

```
 import boto3
 dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
 table = dynamodb.Table('DynamoTable')
 from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
 resp = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('column1'))
```

It requires `Key().eq()` or `Key().begin_with()` ...

I tried with `resp = table.scan()` already, but the response data is too many fields while I only need `column1`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely use [Scan operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html). Check the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html#GettingStarted.Python.04.Scan) to implement it with python.

Regarding how to select just a specific attribute you could use:

```
import boto3

def getColumn1Items():
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('DynamoTable')
    response = table.scan()

    return [i['column1'] for i in response['Items']]
```

You have to iterate over the the entire table and just fetch the column you need.

Comment: Thanks. It's easier than I thought a lot. :D

Comment: Note that scan operation performs a full table scan and reads all the contents of a table. This can be problematic for performance once the amount of data increases.

Answer (score 16):

This lets you get the required column directly and you do not need to iterate over the whole dataset

```
import boto3

def getColumn1Items():
     dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
     table = dynamodb.Table('DynamoTable')
     resp = table.scan(AttributesToGet=['column1'])

     return resp['Items']
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit why this is better than the accepted answer?

Comment: Use ProjectionExpression https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#API_Scan_RequestSyntax

Comment: Old but still relevant :) This is better, because no extra columns are fetched from the database. scan implementation above selects all columns and drops them 'locally'.